# Puedo imprimir solo numeros impares en una matriz?

Tags: java, netbeans

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Si me pudieran ayudar como imprimir solo los numeros impares en una matriz

Comment: Hola, bienvenido a stackoverflow, te recomiendo que cambies la imagen por un bloque de código para que sea más fácil copiarlo. De paso,  puedes leer el siguiente link [¿Cómo preguntar?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) para mejorar tus preguntas futuras.

Answer (score 1):

Sí que puedes hacerlo. Debes **recorrer el array e ir asignando valores según la condición** que le quieras dar (en nuestro caso, que el valor que introduce el usuario sea impar). Para ello, puedes hacer uso de do-while + if como muestro en la propuesta que te adjunto.

```
    public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner src = new Scanner(System.in);
    int entradaUsuario;
    int[][] myArray = new int[2][4];

    for (int i = 0; i<myArray.length; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < myArray[i].length; j++) {
            do{
                System.out.println("Introduce un número impar para" + "[" + i + "]" + " y " + "[" + j + "]:");
                entradaUsuario = src.nextInt();
                if (entradaUsuario%2 != 0){
                    myArray[i][j] = entradaUsuario;
                }else{
                    System.out.println("\tEl valor introducido no es válido.");
                }
            }while(entradaUsuario%2 == 0);
        }
    }
    
    for (int i = 0; i < myArray.length; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < myArray[i].length; j++) {
            System.out.print(myArray[i][j] + " | ");
        }
        System.out.println("");
    }
}
```

Salida:

```
Introduce un número impar para[0] y [0]:
1
Introduce un número impar para[0] y [1]:
2
    El valor introducido no es válido.
Introduce un número impar para[0] y [1]:
3
Introduce un número impar para[0] y [2]:
4
    El valor introducido no es válido.
Introduce un número impar para[0] y [2]:
5
Introduce un número impar para[0] y [3]:
7
Introduce un número impar para[1] y [0]:
9
Introduce un número impar para[1] y [1]:
7
Introduce un número impar para[1] y [2]:
5
Introduce un número impar para[1] y [3]:
3

1 | 3 | 5 | 7 | 
9 | 7 | 5 | 3 |
```

Comment: Muchas gracias!!!